Python class attribute with a value of type inherited class
I am making a game in Python with Pyglet and currently I am tring to involve some menu screens or end screens. I made a class called Screen and the screens (for example GameScreen) inherit from it. The Screen class has a class attribute, s, which is the current screen to be displayed. How am I supposed to assign some Screen object to it?
This is my code:
# main.py

import pyglet
from screen import *

w = pyglet.window.Window()

@w.event
def on_draw():
    w.clear()
    Screen.s.on_draw()

pyglet.app.run()

# screen.py

class Screen:
    s = MainMenuScreen() # of course doesn't work

    def __init__(self): pass
    def on_draw(self): pass


class MainMenuScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buttons = [...]
        ...

    def on_draw(self):
        for button in self.buttons: button.draw()


class GameScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = Player(0, 0)
        ...

    def on_draw(self):
        self.player.draw()


It doesn't sound like screen should be controlling which screen is being displayed, that sounds like the job of a game manager or screen manager class

If I got it right, you can just set the sclass attribute anywhere in mainjust using Screen.s = <some Screen instance>. If you want to keep the list of instances within the class to do the toggling internally, you need to change the class constructor.

Just an example of how the class constructor can be modified to keep track of created screen instances so you can later toggle/obtain the active screen with additional methods activate_screen and show_active
class Screen:
    s = None                     # the active screen
    instance_dict = {}           # the list of all instances
    def __new__(cls):
        # keep all new instances in a directory as lists indexed by class
        if cls not in __class__.instance_dict:
            __class__.instance_dict[cls] = []
        instance = object.__new__(cls)
        __class__.instance_dict[cls].append(instance)
        return instance
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def activate_screen(self):
        # check that instance is in the directory before becoming active
        if self in __class__.instance_dict[self.__class__]:
            __class__.s = self
    @staticmethod
    def show_active():
        return __class__.s
    def on_draw(self):
        pass

class MainMenuScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buttons = []
    def on_draw(self):
        for button in self.buttons: button.draw()

class GameScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = (0, 0)
    def on_draw(self):
        self.player.draw()

print("activating the main Screen")
ms=MainMenuScreen()
ms.activate_screen()
print("active             :", ms.show_active())
print("switching to a game Screen")
gs=GameScreen()
gs.activate_screen()
print("active (from gs)   :", gs.show_active())
print("active (from ms)   :", ms.show_active())
print("active (from class):", Screen.s)

Output
activating the main Screen
active             : <__main__.MainMenuScreen object at 0x10b07df10>
switching to a game Screen
active (from gs)   : <__main__.GameScreen object at 0x10b07d2d0>
active (from ms)   : <__main__.GameScreen object at 0x10b07d2d0>
active (from class): <__main__.GameScreen object at 0x10b07d2d0>

